# JSON.serialize Question - Slack integration

Tags: apex, json

I am looking to create a slack payload. I am struggling to create this payload in Apex.

```
{
        "username": "Bot Name",
        "text": "*Call Recording* :tada:",
        "attachments":[
            {
            "author_name": "Dean",
            "title": "Call Recording",
            "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
            "color": "#36a64f",
             "fields": [
                    {
                        "title": "Account",
                        "value": "var",
                        "short": true
                    },
                 {
                        "title": "Contact",
                        "value": "var",
                        "short": true
                 }
                 ]
             }

        ],
        "icon_emoji": ":dromedary_camel:"
    }
```

So far I have created the following:

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
            gen.writeStartObject(); //Inserts {
            gen.writeStringField('channel', r.channel);
            gen.writeStringField('icon_emoji', ':dromedary_camel:'); 
            gen.writeStringField('username', r.bot_username_var);
            gen.writeStringField('text', r.title_var);
            gen.writeFieldName('attachments');
                gen.writeStartArray();
                    gen.writeStartObject();

                        gen.writeStringField('author_name', r.rep_var);
                        gen.writeStringField('title', r.call_recording_title_var);
                        gen.writeStringField('title_link', r.call_recording_title_var);
                        gen.writeStringField('color', '#36a64f');
                        gen.writeFieldName('fields');
                        gen.writeStartArray();
                            gen.writeStartObject();
                                gen.writeStringField('title', 'Account');
                                gen.writeStringField('value', r.account_var);
                                gen.writeStringField('short', true);
                            gen.writeEndObject();
                            gen.writeStartObject();
                                gen.writeStringField('title', 'Contact');
                                gen.writeStringField('value', r.contact_var);
                                gen.writeStringField('short', true);
                            gen.writeEndObject();

                        gen.writeEndArray();

                    gen.writeEndObject();
                gen.writeEndArray();
            gen.writeEndObject(); //Inserts }

            String body = gen.getAsString(); //Translates JSONGenerator to string to be passed to callout
```

Comment: This might help -- https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Wow, there has to be an easier way

Comment: Don't ever use `JSONGenerator`. It is slow, more complicated, and usage of it leads to more complicated or lower value tests.

Comment: @AdrianLarson so what would you recommend?

Comment: Use the built in `JSON.serialize` and `JSON.deserialize` methods. Create a class to model your data structure so that you can use that for the target/source of those methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way for you to do this is to leverage a custom class, like so:

Classes (you can put them all inside of a larger class, or keep them as individual Apex Classes

```
public class mySlackPayload {
  public String username;
  public String text;

  public List<mySlackAttachment> attachments;
  <the rest of your props go here>

}

public class mySlackAttachment {
  <attachment props go here>
}
```

Then, in your current code, you can do this

```
mySlackPayload myPayload = new mySlackPayload();
myPayload.username = 'xxx';
<fill the rest of the props>

String serializedPayload = JSON.serialize(myPayload);
```

Doing this with sObjects will add extraneous properties added by Apex that will mess up that payload un-necessarily. You can also add constructors to those classes to take an sObject as a parameter and populate properties accordingly.

PS: The tool described in comments by @kurunve should generate this custom class for you (I admit I find the result of that class a bit bloated), then you would simply use the second part of my code to populate and call it.

Comment: Should I look into the JSONGenerator class? 

JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

Comment: I don't think it makes sense. When you serialize a class it'll come out neat as you specified in your original post. But you have to build that class first to mimic the JSON output you want

Comment: why are you doing JSON.serialize(mySlackPayload) I thought you would do JSON.serialize(myPayload)

Comment: Because that class has the shape of the JSON you want to send.

Comment: Your updated code is creating JSON via a generator. You should really prefer serializing a class over that.

Comment: why are you doing JSON.serialize(mySlackPayload) I thought you would do JSON.serialize(myPayload)

Comment: Oh, that is correct, and a typo. Fixing that.

Comment: @MatthewMetros - seconding Sebastian's solution as that is what I did for my Slack integration with one exception - I added a `toJson()` method on `MySlackPayload` class to make it a bit more OO